# How to check if fargate instance is already running

Tags: go, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-go

How do I check if an AWS Fargate instance is already running in golang?

I was thinking of providing a name in the config so when you try to start another instance with one already running it doesn't work because the name is the same.

This is how I'm starting the task:

```
    client := ecs.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    runTaskIn := &ecs.RunTaskInput{
        TaskDefinition: aws.String(appConfig.TaskDefinitionArn),
        Cluster:        aws.String(appConfig.Cluster),
        NetworkConfiguration: &types.NetworkConfiguration{
            AwsvpcConfiguration: &types.AwsVpcConfiguration{
                Subnets: []string{
                    appConfig.SubnetID,
                },
                AssignPublicIp: types.AssignPublicIpEnabled,
            },
        },
        LaunchType: types.LaunchTypeFargate,
    }
```

Could setting the ReferenceId be a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html#API_RunTask_RequestSyntax) value on the task for this purpose. Set the `group` to something specific to this task. Then before running any new tasks you would first list/describe all the running tasks, and check if any of them have that group name already.

Comment: Can you show an example using this func https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ecs#Client.ListTasks